# Error when to tutorial in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When i study ruby on rails with tutorial in http://arubystory.blogspot.gr/2013/11/tutorial-saying-hello-world-with-ruby.html
Apter i add the following line `root to: 'pages#home'` to file `config/routes.rb` but it don't show page hello world in browser, it show.

```
Template is missing
Missing template pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Users/Thang/tutorials/hello_world/app/views"
```

Thank you

Comment: Your template file called home inside the pages folder is missing.
Create home.html.erb in your pages folder in app/views/pages.

Comment: Are you sure you do not `have home.html.erb` file in "C:/Users/Thang/tutorials/hello_world/app/views" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template file called home inside the pages folder is missing. The route is referring to the action **home** in the **pages_controller.rb** aswell as the html file called **home.html.erb**

Create home.html.erb in app/views/pages.